# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS while accessing Wordpress on linux site on HTTPS

Tags: wordpress

Scenario/Background:

- We have created Wordpress on linux Web App on azure.
- Created My SQL server.
- Uploaded all the contents of existing application to Azure using FTP.
- Restored Database using My SQL workBench by Changing storage engine to InnoDB from MyISAM.
- Configured Custom Domains to this Web App and also uploaded SSL certificate and Done SNI binding.
- Updated the database connection detail and below site detail in `wp-config.php`.
- `define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com');`
- `define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');`
- We have not done any changes to `.htaccess` file.

Problem Statement:

While accessing `https://www.example.com`, we are getting below error :

```
www.example.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Website is working fine on http... Problem is with just https... Is there any stuff we need to change from coding or anything else we should implement before directing to https.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code to your **wp-config.php** :

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

It works for me, hope works for you too.